# asp.net return to url withen action filter

Tags: url, redirect, action-filter

```
var url = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

I got the url for the previous action that make the call,
so to redirect to that url within action filter

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: I am developing a custom action filter that will check for some condition if it fulfilled the user will pass to the next action and if not I want to return the user the previous (which we coming from)action